# Virtual Box Failed at starting because of vboxdrv in 13.10

Tags: virtualbox

After upgrading to the latest version of  Virtual Box , It show the message below when I starting a virtual machine

[image: vobx]

Run /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.8.0-31-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

/var/log/vbox-install.log

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
  removing old DKMS module vboxhost version  4.3.4

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.3.4
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.4/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-4.3.4

DKMS: add completed.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

run sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic' has no installation candidate
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by download the latest version of Virtual Box at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Please mark this Answer as solved :)